# How to update doc fields using office.js api

Tags: office-js

I want to update all custom property fields of document with new value if they are present. I am using insertText() function here but seems its not working for fields. I need some function to update field values with the given (doc custom property) values. Here is my code.

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    var customDocProps = context.document.properties.customProperties;
    // first, load custom properties object
    context.load(customDocProps);
    return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            // now load actual property
            var filenameProp = customDocProps.getItemOrNullObject("PW", { matchPrefix: true });
            context.load(filenameProp);
            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    if (customDocProps.items.length > 0) {
                        var fields = context.document.body.fields.load("items");
                        fields.load(["code", "result"]);
                        return context.sync()
                            .then(function () {
                                if (fields.items.length > 0) {
                                    $.each(fields.items, function (i, k) {
                                        $.each(customDocProps.items, function (j, l) {
                                            if (k.code.trim().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').split(' ')[1].toLowerCase() == l.key.toLowerCase()) {
                                                //replace if values are different
                                                if (k.result.text != l.value) {                                                
                                                    k.result.insertText(k.result.text, l.value);
                                                    k.load(["code", "result"]);
                                                    return context.sync();
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    return false;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                    }
                });
        });
}).catch(function (error) {
    debugger;
    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The field can be updated in this way:
k.result.insertText(k.result.text, loc);
The loc could be string of "Start" "End" "Before" "After" "Replace".

I notice the customProperties.getItemOrNullObject has only one input parameter.Would you please refer to this link : [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.custompropertycollection?view=word-js-preview#word-word-custompropertycollection-getitemornullobject-member(1)) and check if there's syntax errors.

After I revised the getItemOrNullObject to only one parameter, I put several console.log("flag") in your code and force the if condition to always true. The whole code can be executed successfully and the log can also be  output to console. I think you could check the if conditions and try to log to see if every variable value is correct.